# Excel discard user event?

Tags: vba, excel, activex, labview

I have an Excel sheet that updates every 1 Second (via Labview using ActiveX)and has to be visible to the user.
And I cannot set "Application.UserInteractive" to "FALSE" throughout the application as the User could use the system for other excel operations.
And I have the same problem with "WorkSheet.UserInterfaceOnly"

The problem that occurs is:
If the user has selected a range of data ("mousedown" and has not released it) and at the same time the software tries to write the data .... boop it doesn't work...
I can set it to wait  until user release the mouse click.... But is there a way to prevent this problem by not allowing to detect mouseclick events or block it some other way

Answer (score 1):

Well Anywho...
I found a simple solution....
Protect the worksheet and set EnableSelection to noSelection